# I am getting an "invalid syntax" and i dont know why

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

The "Introduction to Computing Using Python" book tells me to type this in 1st = [23.99, 19.99, 34.50, 120.99] but all i get is this.

```
1st = [23.99, 19.99, 34.50, 120.99]
  File "<ipython-input-129-92c8166c6dfe>", line 1
    1st = [23.99, 19.99, 34.50, 120.99]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you cannot start a variable name with a number. Change the name from `1st` to `first` for example, and it will work.

A variable name must start with an underscore (`_`) or a letter. See the section in [this article](http://www.thehelloworldprogram.com/python/python-variable-assignment-statements-rules-conventions-naming/) with the heading **The Rules**. The rest of the article should be interesting to you as well if you are new to Python.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Mark this one as the solution.